# Auto dated google drive folder on upload

Tags: google-drive-api

I have been out of the programming world for some time and so am looking for any help that you may be able to provide.

I am trying to create a Google drive set up that automatically creates a new folder that is titled "mm/dd/yyyy" when it receives it's first upload of the day. The files will then continue to automatically be assigned to that folder until a 12.01am the next day, which is when another new folder would be generated once an upload is completed on that day...etc etc. Ideally the script would not create a mandatory folder every day as there will not be uploads everyday, it would only take action once the "command" of a file, photo, video is being uploaded.

Any help would be a massive help. Thanks guys.

P.s no I do not have a script to share I am relearning as we speak.

Comment: At Google Drive, in order to upload files in the folder, at first it is required to retrieve folder ID. So please create a new folder and retrieve ID, and then, upload files by giving the folder ID. In this case, you can use [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/). If this information not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a programmable pattern for this.

1. Create a folder using `Files:create` api. See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
2. Set a logic when you want to upload a file/photo/video using `Files:insert` or `Files:update`. See [Files Insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/insert) and [Files update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update).
3. When there's an update from your folder created, you can use the property:

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwau.png)
4. Pass that property as date format ***"mm/dd/yyyy"*** to `Files:update`:

   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9lXB.png)
5. This will trigger again the `Files:create` api.

For more informations:

- [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/manage-uploads)
- [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/folder)